# regular expressions to add a slash to the end of a generic string of words

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm in notepad++ and I need to add a / right before the closing  > in the following line:

```
<meta name="description" content="*****">
```

the `*****` above is a bunch of text that I need left in place, and it changes from page to page, thus my need for some find / replace method that is superior to what I would normally be capable of.  I assume regex would be the right way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the trick for me (in NP++):

Find: `(<meta name="description" [^>]+)>`

Replace with: `\1/>`

Has some caveats, but it'll work for a simple search/replace, which it sounds like you're doing. Was I right in assuming that you're trying to only do this on `<meta>` tags with attributes of `name="description"`?

Edit - Tested it with the Replace All button and went from this:

```
<meta name="description" content="ljfkdl">
<meta name="description" content="039814">
<meta name="description" content="lkjai983j">
<meta name="description" content="whak.dlai3#">
<meta name="description" content="ljfdal&&3lk">
<meta name="description" content="a b c ake87">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="description" content="memememe">
<meta name="description" content="alkd3988aj38#!">
```

To this:

```
<meta name="description" content="ljfkdl"/>
<meta name="description" content="039814"/>
<meta name="description" content="lkjai983j"/>
<meta name="description" content="whak.dlai3#"/>
<meta name="description" content="ljfdal&&3lk"/>
<meta name="description" content="a b c ake87"/>
<meta name="description" content=""/>
<meta name="description" content="memememe"/>
<meta name="description" content="alkd3988aj38#!"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on these assumptions:

- Tags are all almost well-formed except for the missing `/` i.e. no raw `>` characters within attributes, etc
- The value of the `name` attribute is disregarded since all `<meta />` tags should self-close anyway

Find:

```
(<meta[^>]*)[^/]>
```

Replace with:

```
\1 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Though HTML and regular expressions don't usually mix well, this seems like a simple enough of a case. (I'm assuming that you're looking for all meta tags, and don't care about what else is inside. Being more specific can be helpful, though :D)

```
<(meta[^>]+)>
```

Will find content between `<` and `>` and return that inner content as a subgroup.

Depending on the Notepad++ notation, you should replace with something like this:

```
<\1/>
```

(Or possibly $1 instead of \1, or something else entirely. Again, dunno what Notepad++ wants.)

This regular expression doesn't catch cases in which `>` is part of an attribute, like `<fake-math-tag expression="4 > 2">` but is probably good enough for your situation. (This is where the "don't mix well" bit kicks in.)

Answer (score 0):

Searching text: `<(meta.*)>`
Replace to: `<\1/>`